# Yii/Giix - Controller Error when saving to related tables

Tags: yii-extensions, yii

When testing a CRUD generated Create form I receive the following error.  Anyone familiar with this problem?  Thanks ahead of time.

undefined index: contactindivs

```
07         $this->render('view', array(
08             'model' => $this->loadModel($id, 'Companylocation'),
09         ));
10     }
11 
12     public function actionCreate() {
13         $model = new Companylocation;
14 
15 
16         if (isset($_POST['Companylocation'])) {
17             $model->setAttributes($_POST['Companylocation']);
18             $relatedData = array(
19                 'contactindivs' => $_POST['Companylocation']['contactindivs'] === '' ? null : $_POST['Companylocation']['contactindivs'],
20                 );
21 
22             if ($model->saveWithRelated($relatedData)) {
23                 if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
24                     Yii::app()->end();
25                 else
26                     $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->CompanyLocationID));
27             }
28         }
29 
30         $this->render('create', array( 'model' => $model));
31     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 19 is stating that if contactindivs === '' make it null.  change it to this and it shouldn't give the error.

```
$contactindivs = isset($_POST['Companylocation']['contactindivs']) ? $_POST['Companylocation']['contactindivs'] : '';
$relatedData = array(
     'contactindivs' => $contactindivs,);
```

The problem is that your getting a warning because you check for 'Companylocation', but not for ['Companylocation']['contactindivs'].  That should fix it.

Comment: Thx for quick response Eric.  Unfortunately this is getting an error.  Is there a way to write it without the isset() similar to how I had it before?  I think your code has a syntax error, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Change the first colon into a question mark (ternary operator).

Comment: @laser_wizard, I have added a second solution.

Comment: Thx guys, I'm headed in to work on it now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, that fixed that particular problem.  Still not saving to the database so I'll create a new ticket.

Comment: check your config file. I know that Yii's documents arent the easiest to understand, but search online for a db tutorial.   It will probably do you some good to go through it.